# Camel unit testing hits custom component

Tags: java, routes, apache-camel

I have camel project with component(endpoint) written. It is used in routes (mycomponent:somename) My unit tests for routes started failing after component was finished.
(it uses some http communication with own client written) I can see error according to "unable to connect to server...", "unable to read property....".

So, looks like endpoint is not replaced with direct I used for this purposes.
What I need, real unit testing for route, I don't need to start web service to run some tests, it should be just route testing.

Sample code:

```
public class MyTest extends CamelTestSupport {

@Override
public String isMockEndpoints() {
    return "*";
}

@Override
protected RouteBuilder createRouteBuilder() throws Exception {
    return new RouteBuilder() {
        @Override
        public void configure() throws Exception {
            includeRoutes(new MyRoute());
        }
    };
}

@Test
public void testRouteToRd() throws Exception {
    context.getRouteDefinitions().get(0).adviceWith(context, new AdviceWithRouteBuilder() {

        @Override
        public void configure() throws Exception {
            replaceFromWith("direct:incomponent");   // replacing from
        }
    });

    getMockEndpoint("mock:myconnector:outcomponent").expectedMessageCount(1);
    template.sendBody("direct:incomponent", OK_MESSAGE);  // and sending to direct
    assertMockEndpointsSatisfied();
}
}
```

Why did I began hitting real component with this configuration (it was working well before component was finished) 
Can someone help, thanks.

I am so sorry, but copy pasting and "playing" with configuration helped me. Replaced

```
@Override
public String isMockEndpoints() {
    return "*";
}
```

with:

```
@Override
public String isMockEndpointsAndSkip() {
    return "*";
}
```

And all my tests are good now. But Still don't understand why this is happening, I replace in endpoint with direct and sending message to direct (not to real)

So, extremely sorry, if it is not good question, please close.

Answer (score 0):

When you use `adviceWith` in a Camel test, you have to override the method `isUseAdviceWith` and then call `context.start()` before you send your data in.

Example:

```
 @Override
public boolean isUseAdviceWith() {
    // tell we are using advice with, which allows us to advice the route
    // before Camel is being started
    return true;
}

@Test
public void testRouteToRd() throws Exception {
context.getRouteDefinitions().get(0).adviceWith(context, new AdviceWithRouteBuilder() {

    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {
        replaceFromWith("direct:incomponent");   // replacing from
    }
});

context.start(); // NECESSARY IF USING ADVICEWITH

getMockEndpoint("mock:myconnector:outcomponent").expectedMessageCount(1);
template.sendBody("direct:incomponent", OK_MESSAGE);  // and sending to direct
assertMockEndpointsSatisfied();
```

}

Reference: [Camel AdviceWith documentation](http://camel.apache.org/advicewith.html)